# Getting Date + 30 days in Typescript

Tags: typescript, datetime

I am new to Typescript and trying to get the date + (X) amount of months or days from now, in the `newDate` format specified below...

When I try to add one month:

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 2;
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

var newDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

It returns:

```
13/6/2022
```

When I try to add 30 days instead:

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate() + 30;
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

var newDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
```

It returns this:

```
12/36/2022
```

So not only are the month & day incorrect in the example, the year doesn't advance either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using Moment or any other library you can use `setDate()` and `getDate()` functions to manipulate value of `dateObj`:

```js
// hard-coded date to illustrate automatic handling of year/month change
var dateObj = new Date('2022-12-06');

// add 30 days
dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + 30); // 2023-01-05

var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

var newDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

console.log(newDate)
```

Notice how it automatically takes care of changing the month and year automatically for you.

Comment: This is a good/simple solution (deleted my answer about the use of moment).

Answer (score 2):

Simply set date with `setSate()` function.

```
var future = new Date();
future.setDate(future.getDate() + X_DAYS);
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74706029/438273), you can rely on the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object's ability to accept and handle invalid (out of range) values when adjusting specific components (e.g. day of month) — it will wrap the number and algorithmically determine how to handle the overflow (remainder), applying it to the next component (e.g. month).

> e.g. In the details, adding `30` to `6` results in `36` as the new day of month — that's not a valid value for any month in the JS `Date` object.

If you don't want to rely on that kind of behavior for some reason — maybe you want a conceptual solution that you could apply to another language or date framework that doesn't handle overflow for you — then you can also adjust the numeric date representation manually using a bit of [unit conversion math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_units):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygUxgXhmZB3GARJZACgJQDoBVAFQGEiAmABnvoBoYBGD9gNgEo+AbgBQoSCAA2yMhJABzIonJQQASQDKAeXVQATgEswCgYJgB6MzCYsAtB3o3GPKo0YAuVx8ZlXjAFrCouDQ8AgAnqpgALIQ6Jy+MABUMDyMSSlpyfQALCIWMAWFRUUAthBmscUlhmYAFrrC+cXNLTDl1WDF9WaIYYFK0hDIUFT6JcQDZHLDo+NEfDAA1DBEAMyZoRHRECaNlq0FAHrHJ6enRWeXh3sHBQMwhjBlreubsY9lgWIQktKyCpMVBptHpDMYhOZLNZVo4OI4AKwudyeVw+VwBIA)

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 11, 6));
console.log(date.toISOString()); // 2022-12-06T00:00:00.000Z

const dayInMs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
//              ms/s      min/hr
//                    s/min     hr/day

date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * dayInMs));
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//           date in ms        30 days in ms

console.log(date.toISOString()); // 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000Z
```